# How to connect mysql with c++ and run the program in dev c++

Tags: c++, mysql, database, dev-c++

How do I connect the c++ program to the MySQL database and run it with a dev c++ compiler?

I downloaded MySQL connecter c++ 8.0 and I wrote a program but the compiler is telling:

> #include "mysql_connection.h" no such file or directory.

How do I tell my compiler that this file exists or include that file?

Comment: IMHO, you should use the C language native connection code.  I have had unsolvable issues compiling and linking the C++ connector.

Comment: Which compiler or IDE are you using?  Different compilers and IDEs have different methods for specifying the search paths for #include files.

Comment: I am using dev c++ i had downloaded the mysql c++ connecter version 8.0 but my compiler cannot recognise the includes files of the mysql connector